# Does Xcode 4.3 include Quartz Composer?

Tags: xcode, quartz-composer

I just installed Xcode 4.3 from the App Store. As I started it first, it asked if I want to delete existing 4.2.

Does 4.3 include Quartz Composer? Where is it located? Or should I say no and keep 4.2 for QC?

Answer (score 30):

**No.**

But you can download Quartz Composer separately:  http://developer.apple.com/ > login with valid developer Id > Mac > View all downloads > Graphics Tools for Xcode.

Answer (score 13):

Slightly faster instructions:

- Visit https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Graphics
- Log in
- Download the "Graphics Tools for Xcode" DMG

[image]

Answer (score 12):

This has changed. Open XCode. In the top menu go to XCode > Open Developer Tools > More Developer Tools > and then download the "Graphics Tools for Xcode"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it does or not, but you can always install 4.3 alongside 4.2. Just choose to install it in a different directory (I usually name my extra installations using the version of Xcode, like "Developer 4.3"). So you can go ahead with the installation and check for Quartz Composer. If you decide to use Xcode 4.3, just remove your existing "Developer" folder and rename your "Developer 4.3" folder to "Developer".

Answer (score 0):

Quartz Composer is part of **Graphics Tools**, which you can easily download from Apple Developer website :) Some tools are now available as separate downloads since Xcode 4.

Please note that **Quartz frameworks** and **Quarts Composer View** are already available on Xcode 4, so you can embed Quartz compositions without a problem into Xcode app. If you want create Quartz compositions, just download the latest **Graphics Tools** pack from Apple Dev Download site.